# ANTLR4: Is it possible to match for a piece of content that is NOT followed by a token?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am using ANTLR 4.7.

The input looks like this:

```
[section a]
bla bla bla

[section b] <<<<<<< to ignore
bla bla bla <<<<<<< to ignore

[section c]
bla bla bla
```

How to igonre the whole content in `[section b]`?

Currently, I am using a lexer rule like below:

```
Section_Igonre : '[section b]' (~'[')* ->skip;
```

I use the `[` as an indicator of the start of next section. So the ignore shoud stop there.

But I am afraid this is not so reliable if the section b content contains `[`. So I want to first use a token to match the section tag. And then use the token as an indicator to stop ignore.

```
SectionTag : '[' [a-zA-Z]+ ']';
```

Is this possible? I tried below but ANTLR refused it:

```
Section_Igonre : '[section b]' (~SectionTag )* ->skip;
```

The error says:

> severity: 'Error' message: 'rule reference SectionTag is not currently
>   supported in a set'

Answer (score 0):

This is most conveniently done in your Visitor or Listener class, after a successful parse.  It's much like the problem [answered here by another high-reputation ANTLR expert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437040/antlr-recognize-single-character).

I would just let it parse, and create an empty Listener or Visitor override that does absolutely nothing with the section you're mentioning.

Comment: The problem is,  I just want to find a way to skip arbitrary sections given the section name. So I dont need to figure out grammars for each of them. There are so many of them and each section is so different.  And if I can skip them, I can save the memory footprint.

Comment: Maybe preprocess your input and remove everything you are not interested in (provided you have a pair of unique delimiters that are easy to find). Feed the outcome of this filtering process to your parser then.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thanks. Thant's one option. If I have no other choices. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there appears to be a typo in Section_*Igonre* which might have been your entire issue!

Anyhow, try this, HTH.

```
grammar ini;
prog : section+ EOF ;
section : ( SectionIgnore | SectionTag ) BODYTEXT
    ;
SectionIgnore : '[section b]'  (~'[')*
    { System.out.println("got an ignored sectiontag !");}
    -> skip
    ;
SectionTag : '[' [a-zA-Z ]+? ']' NEWLINE
    { System.out.println("got a sectiontag !");}
    ;
BODYTEXT : (~'[')* NEWLINE
    { System.out.println("got BODYTEXT!");}
    ;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;
```

I tested it with the following data

```
[section a]
first bla bla bla
two line section

[section b]
bla bla bla <<<<<<< to ignore this section

[section c]
second bla bla bla

[section b]
repeated bla bla bla <<<<<<< to ignore this section
```

And output of `grun` is

```
$ grun ini prog -tree -tokens data
got a sectiontag !
got BODYTEXT!
got an ignored sectiontag !
got a sectiontag !
got BODYTEXT!
got an ignored sectiontag !
[@0,0:11='[section a]\n',<SectionTag>,1:0]
[@1,12:47='first bla bla bla\ntwo line section\n\n',<BODYTEXT>,2:0]
[@2,104:115='[section c]\n',<SectionTag>,8:0]
[@3,116:135='second bla bla bla\n\n',<BODYTEXT>,9:0]
[@4,201:200='<EOF>',<EOF>,14:0]
(prog 
(section [section a]\n first bla bla bla\ntwo line section\n\n) 
(section [section c]\n second bla bla bla\n\n)
<EOF>)
$
```